# How is the Chinese officialdom, press, or intelligentsia discussing Russia's possible use of nuclear weapons in the Ukraine war?

Tags: russian-federation, china, armed-conflict, ukraine, nuclear-weapons

It's certainly known that the Chinese press and officials have openly blamed [NATO](https://www.reuters.com/world/china-blames-nato-pushing-russia-ukraine-tension-breaking-point-2022-03-09/) and [the USA](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/8/10/china-accuses-us-as-main-instigator-of-the-war-in-ukraine) more specifically for the war in Ukraine.

On the other hand, China officially has a ["no first use"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/25751654.2018.1458415) policy for nuclear weapons.

So, how have Chinese circles of power or their press/academic proxies discussed the various open calls of Russian officials [like those of Kadyrov](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-says-its-troops-left-lyman-avoid-encirclement-2022-10-01/) for the use of (low yield) nuclear weapons in Ukraine, or the slightly more vague allusions of Putin to ["all weapons at our disposal"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75761/vagueness-rather-than-specificity-when-the-risks-are-enormous)?

I don't really expect Chinese officials to publically delve into these Russian statements (would be glad to be proven wrong though), but in a country like China, in which press and academia often are well aligned to the power, one can get a feeling of how the officialdom may be leaning from the press and academics. So, if Chinese officials said nothing on the matter of Russian officials' open calls or allusions to the use nuclear weapons in defense of their [recently expanded country](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/9/30/putin-announces-russian-annexation-of-four-ukrainian-regions), what are the Chinese press or academics saying about these open calls and allusions to the use of nuclear weapons?

Comment: If anyone is curious about what China said about the annexation/accession of 4 Ukrainian regions by/to Russia (depending on your POV), I was able to (easily) find out [that](https://www.newsweek.com/china-response-condemning-vladimir-putin-taking-ukraine-territory-1748088) China has reaffirmed in general terms the principles of territorial integrity, but has not explicitly condemned the recent Russian decrees. (They did explicitly condemn the expansion of NATO though, in the recent past.)

Comment: My speculation is under the table, China has expressed uneasiness about Russia's action and is disappointed in its failure to end the war effectively. If nuclear war starts, China inevitably will be affected as the nuclear fallouts are to close to home.

Comment: Most of the time assuming that China has a unified stance on some international topic but publically it is not fully known is a reasonable assumption. However, with the upcoming end of Xi's second 5 year term in mid October there are various signs of internal power struggles within the leadership of China. Pro Xi wants to give more help and support to Russia, the anti Xi groups (let by the Premier Li Keqiang) have a more anti Russia stance.

Comment: @quarague I've just asked [Is there any acknowledge opposition whatsoever to Xi as a potential candidate for party leader this October? Any others publicly discussed?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/76055/16047)

Answer (score 0):

China once proposed the [12 item plan](http://my.china-embassy.gov.cn/eng/zgxw/202302/t20230224_11030881.htm) how do they think Ukrainian crisis could be resolved.

There is no suggestion or approval for either side to strike with nuclear weapons between these items. There is instead a proposal to respect territorial integrity of other countries that does not look like a strong support of this, as you say, "recent expansion" (some would use [other](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/russia-ukraine-war-putin-annexation-donetsk-luhansk-zaporizhzhia-rcna118197) words).

I doubt if any country ever proposed another such a "solution" for any problem.